# Calculus of Variation Problem

Tags: calculus

We have $$J[y]=\int_0^2y^2(x)(1-y'(x))^2\mathrm{d}x$$
subject to $y(0)=0$ and $y(2)=1$. Then the natural guess is $$\phi(x)=\left\{\begin{aligned}&0&&0\leq x\leq 1\\&x-1&&1\leq x\leq 2\end{aligned}\right.$$

I am reading the note of calculus of variation.  I don't understand why the first solution is at the domain $[0, 1]$ and the second one is $[1, 2]$.

Anyone help me to understand it, please.

Answer (score 3):

You want to make the integral as small as possible. Let's start at $y(2) = 1$ and intuitively draw the function backwards which minimizes the integral. Notice that the integrand must be nonnegative. We can in fact try to make it $0$ for as long as possible. Well, if we have to reach $y(0) = 0$ piecewise differentiably, we have to slope down at some point. To make the second factor $(1 - y'(x))^2$ vanish, let's choose a constant slope of $y'(x) = 1$ and go along a straight line. But then when we reach $x = 1$ we already attain $y(1) = 0$. Now because of the first factor $y(x)^2$ it's probably a good idea to just go horizontally to $y(0) = 0$. So we found a piecewise differentiable function for which the integral given is $0$, which is the smallest possible by nonnegativity.

Comment: Thank you. Pratyush Sarkar.

Answer (score 2):

To minimize the second factor, you want $y'$ to be close to $1$. To minimize the first factor you want $y$ to be close to $0$. So a natural guess might be to stay at $0$ as long as you can and only start going up to $1$ once you can do that with slope $1$, which is at $x=1$.

Comment: Thank you for your time, oriki